# How to see which Vue Version is installed in Laravel and how to update?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.5, package.json

In package.json I see the line: "vue": "^2.1.10", but doing npm update I see: vue@2.5.13.

Which Vue version is installed in my Laravel App? Is there another way to see it?

And how would you update Vue to Version 2.5.13 if it is still on 2.1.10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to `package.json` under `dependencies` you can find `"vue": "^2.1.10"` if you wish to change version, just edit to the version you want and run `npm update` or `npm install`

Or if you wish to do it through npm then

```
npm remove vue

npm install vue@2.X.X --save
```

Comment: Okay thanks I try this out! Sorry, I'm a bit confused with all the npm, composer, bower and so on.